# =sum(IIF with mid and InStr

Tags: reporting-services, expression

How do I combine these two expressions?

I'd like to put

```
=mid(Fields!Created_By.Value , InStr(Fields!Created_By.Value,"|")+1)
```

inside the following expression:

```
=sum(IIf(Fields!Issue_Status.Value = "New Report", 1, 0),"Incident_Log")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you expect to get when you sum these strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with my problem with:

```
=sum( 

    iif(mid(Fields!Created_By.Value , InStr(Fields!Created_By.Value,"\")+1)=mid(User!UserID , InStr(User!UserID,"\")+1)
            ,iif(Fields!Issue_Status.Value <> "Closed",1,0)
                    ,0)

,"My_Data_Source")
```